# Problems with Unicode and lxml attrib

Tags: python, lxml, amp-html

Having problems getting attributes with lxml when the element contains unicode characters. I've read a lot of other threads that discuss decoding from UTF-8 but I can't seem to get it working. Nothing I've found has given the context in the form of the attributes.

Currently getting the attributes works like so if the html tag doesn't have unicode characters, for instance when I print document and the html tag looks something like this `<html lang="en" class="">` I get `{'lang': 'en', 'class': ''}` as you'd expect from `html_attributes`

```
from urllib import urlopen
from lxml import etree

document = urlopen(url).read()

#Print the document
print(document)

tree = etree.HTML(document)
html_attributes = tree.attrib

# Print the attributes
print(html_attributes)
```

However whenever I give lxml a HTML document document with a unicode attribute on the HTML tag, like so: `<html \u26a1="">` I end up getting an empty object: `{}` from `html_attributes`

Is there a way around this so it will print the unicode attributes?

Comment: I don't recall any specification allowing that representation of characters for attribute names, but I could be mistaken.

Comment: For lxml or HTML in general?

Comment: In Python, `\u26a1` is a reference to the HIGH VOLTAGE SIGN character (U+26A1). Having that string literal as the name of an attribute in a HTML document looks strange.

Comment: @mzjn I agree, but this is allowed via the AMP spec, see here: https://www.ampproject.org/docs/tutorials/create/basic_markup - I'm working on a parser that validates AMP documents but before it does so it detects if it's even an amp document at all. Detecting the `amp` string is no problem if the document uses that, but about only 50% about do.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with lxml but base from [Parsing and Serialisation](http://lxml.de/FAQ.html#parsing-and-serialisation) on why can't lxml parse my XML from unicode strings, XML is explicitly defined as a stream of bytes. That leads to rule number one: do not decode your XML data yourself. Also mentioned, if the unicode string declares an XML encoding internally (<?xml encoding="..."?>), parsing is bound to fail. The same is true for HTML unicode strings that contain charset meta tags. You may want to check the documentation for more information and see if it will help you.